# Yii2 manage custom dependancies

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Ok so I have setup an advanced application in Yii2 and it is all working but now I want to install my own bootstrap which has 48 cols and a gutter width of `20px`.

The only way I currently see is to actually maintain my own repo of it in GitHub or something.

What is the best way with composer controlling everything I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best way I can see is to add this to your config:

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'css' => ['css/bootstrap.css']
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I am completely open to better suggestions.